# what kind of attribute does '@' represent in Mac OS

Tags: html, macos, nginx, attributes

[image]

I'm using nginx to build a web server. By default, there is a folder named `html`, which contains an `index.html` and a `50.html`. If we visit `localhost`, the `index.html` in the folder `html` will be shown.

Now I need to create my own folder containing all of my `.html` files. But when I configure nginx and try to visit them, I always get an 403 error.

For now I'm considering it's the problem of attributes of `.html` files.

I've found that the attributes of `html` folder contain an `@`, whereas my folder doesn't. I want to know what does it mean and how to add such an attribute for my own folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@` signifies that the file has extended permissions attributes beyond the standard `U/G/O`. It could be related to metadata or quarantine functionality. You can view the attributes by using the `xattr` command:

`xattr file.jpg`

You can remove the extended attributes like so:

`xattr -d file.jpg`

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html